# linux bash - ps uax - can not see running script?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, root, ps

it is very very strange and i can't figure this ought-to-be-simple thing out:

1. login as non-root user
2. create a script

```
    user@debian:~$ vim loop.sh

    while true; do
    echo "Yeah!";
    sleep 1;
    done;

    chmod u+x loop.sh; # mark it runnable
    ./loop.sh; # run the script

    Yeah!
    Yeah!
    Yeah!
    ...
```

3. login as root user on a different terminal

`ps uax|grep loop
    -> no result - is this script "invisible" even to root?`

```
tested on:
uname -a
Linux debian 3.16.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1+deb8u2 (2017-03-07) i686 GNU/Linux

vim loop.sh
#!/bin/bash <- added this line
while true; do
echo "Yeah!";
sleep 1;
done;

ps uax|grep loop
user      1282  0.0  0.2   5084  2736 pts/0    S+   14:30   0:00 /bin/bash ./loop.sh <- now i can see it
```

... if this is not mysterious - it seems to be a little strange - and even might have security implications? :-D root can't see what scripts are run by logged in users?

or i am missing something here...

thanks for looking into it.

Comment: Script is not a process itself. Script just contains a list of commands to execute - that's why you don't see the script itself in the process list, only the commands it executes. Even in your last example, loop.sh only shows up as an argument for bash, not as a process.

Answer (score 2):

Your tty spawns a new process for bash script to run. Also, as it contains sleep command a new child process for each sleep command gets spawned.

```
while true do
echo "Yeah!"
echo $$  #Prints pid of running script
sleep 1
done
```

Once you get PID value from this script output. You can do a grep on the same and you will get the process running.

> Script response
>
> ```
> Yeah!
> 54126
> Yeah!
> 54126
> Yeah!
> ```
>
> ps -eaf | grep 54126
>
> ```
> 503 54126 21882   0  6:10PM ttys000    0:00.07 -bash   
> 503 54278 54126   0  6:11PM ttys000    0:00.00 sleep 1   
> 503 54294   425   0  6:11PM ttys001    0:00.00 grep 54126
> ```

Comment: thanks for answering that question :) i voted one up :)

Comment: ok so with ps you can see binaries that are started from bash - but not what scripts (interactively). e.g.: Terminal1: sleep 40; Terminal2: ps uax|grep sleep
canoodle  5328  0.0  0.0   3744   516 pts/1    S+   15:36   0:00 sleep 40
canoodle  5330  0.0  0.0   4556  2320 pts/2    S+   15:36   0:00 grep sleep

Comment: ...unless the script spans a new bash (hase the #!/bin/bash line at the to - but you are correct. every binary called by the script will also have it's own PID/instance... well i just found that to be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

When there is no shebang the current shell opens the script an interprets the content so the process information at os level doesn't have the name of script as when the command is called `bash ./loop.sh`

To retrieve the pid from opened file script file name :

```
fuser ./loop.sh
```

Comment: # yeah works. it basically returns the PID of the bash that the user used to start the script.user /home/user/scripts/loop.sh

/home/user/scripts/loop.sh:  7643

root@debian:/home/user# ps uax|grep 7643

user      7643  0.0  0.3   6560  3752 pts/1    S+   10:27   0:00 -bash

root      7673  0.0  0.2   4556  2104 pts/0    S+   10:27   0:00 grep 7643

# WHY CAN'T I USE <pre> HERE TO FORMAT CODE?